# Does potassium ions have a longer range attraction than sodium ions or hydrogen ions?

Tags: electrostatics, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, ions

Electronegativity decreases with period in in the periodic table. The explanation for that is because the distance to the nucleus decreases with each orbital shell of electrons, if I got that right. What about the ability to attract over distance, how is it affected? Is it instead increased (given the higher positive charge alltogether in the nucleus). As an example, do potassium ions have a longer range attraction than sodium ions or hydrogen ions?

Answer (score 0):

As the number of protons in the nucleus increases, the electronegativity or attraction will increase. This effect generally only holds true for a row in the periodic table because the attraction between charges falls off rapidly with distance. But there is one exception: in the case the distance of attraction is not limited by the atomic radius, the strength of attraction will continue to increase down the rows of the periodic table as well.